# Convert a list of string into tuples

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, floating-point, tuples

I have this list of strings :

```
['(39.2947500000, -76.6565600000)', '(39.3423900000, -76.5698300000)', '(39.3199500000, -76.6222000000)', '(39.2533200000, -76.6263600000)', '(39.3068100000, -76.6549700000)', '(39.2937500000, -76.6233700000)', '(39.3146700000, -76.6425300000)', '(39.3073300000, -76.6015900000)', '(39.2451900000, -76.6336400000)', '(39.3283000000, -76.5893200000)', '(39.3215400000, -76.6736800000)', '(39.3010000000, -76.5977400000)', '(39.3122600000, -76.6194200000)', '(39.3161400000, -76.5663900000)', '(39.3573500000, -76.6005300000)', '(39.3311200000, -76.6315100000)', '(39.3311200000, -76.6315100000)', '(39.2832900000, -76.5996300000)', '(39.2868200000, -76.6063900000)', '(39.3031200000, -76.6461100000)']
```

I need to convert this strings to tuples, so that the output is:

```
[(39.2947500000, -76.6565600000),(39.3423900000, -76.5698300000)......]
```

I tried to use float method but it gives the this error:

ValueError: could not convert string to float: (39.2947500000, -76.6565600000)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my_list = ['(39.2947500000, -76.6565600000)', '(39.3423900000, -76.5698300000)']
print [(float(x.split(',')[0][1:]), float(x.split(',')[1][1:-1])) for x in my_list]
```

This solution does not use eval (which I dislike using), it iterates over the strings, splits them on the ',', substrings them to remove the '(', ' ' and ')' and then casts them to a float

Answer (score 6):

```
>>> L=['(39.2947500000, -76.6565600000)', '(39.3423900000, -76.5698300000)', '(39.3199500000, -76.6222000000)', '(39.2533200000, -76.6263600000)', '(39.3068100000, -76.6549700000)', '(39.2937500000, -76.6233700000)', '(39.3146700000, -76.6425300000)', '(39.3073300000, -76.6015900000)', '(39.2451900000, -76.6336400000)', '(39.3283000000, -76.5893200000)', '(39.3215400000, -76.6736800000)', '(39.3010000000, -76.5977400000)', '(39.3122600000, -76.6194200000)', '(39.3161400000, -76.5663900000)', '(39.3573500000, -76.6005300000)', '(39.3311200000, -76.6315100000)', '(39.3311200000, -76.6315100000)', '(39.2832900000, -76.5996300000)', '(39.2868200000, -76.6063900000)', '(39.3031200000, -76.6461100000)']
>>> import ast
>>> list(map(lambda x:ast.literal_eval(x), L))
[(39.29475, -76.65656), (39.34239, -76.56983), (39.31995, -76.6222), (39.25332, -76.62636), (39.30681, -76.65497), (39.29375, -76.62337), (39.31467, -76.64253), (39.30733, -76.60159), (39.24519, -76.63364), (39.3283, -76.58932), (39.32154, -76.67368), (39.301, -76.59774), (39.31226, -76.61942), (39.31614, -76.56639), (39.35735, -76.60053), (39.33112, -76.63151), (39.33112, -76.63151), (39.28329, -76.59963), (39.28682, -76.60639), (39.30312, -76.64611)]
```

For python 2.x: `map(lambda x:ast.literal_eval(x), L)`

Edit: some explanation:

`ast` stands for Abstract Syntax Tree. `literal_eval()` is much more safe than `eval()`.

Quoting from official doc:

> ast.literal_eval(node_or_string) Safely evaluate an expression node or
>   a Unicode or Latin-1 encoded string containing a Python literal or
>   container display. The string or node provided may only consist of the
>   following Python literal structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists,
>   dicts, booleans, and None.
>
> This can be used for safely evaluating strings containing Python
>   values from untrusted sources without the need to parse the values
>   oneself. It is not capable of evaluating arbitrarily complex
>   expressions, for example involving operators or indexing.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `eval`:

```
a = ['(39.2947500000, -76.6565600000)', '(39.3423900000, -76.5698300000)', '(39.3199500000, -76.6222000000)', '(39.2533200000, -76.6263600000)', '(39.3068100000, -76.6549700000)', '(39.2937500000, -76.6233700000)', '(39.3146700000, -76.6425300000)', '(39.3073300000, -76.6015900000)', '(39.2451900000, -76.6336400000)', '(39.3283000000, -76.5893200000)', '(39.3215400000, -76.6736800000)', '(39.3010000000, -76.5977400000)', '(39.3122600000, -76.6194200000)', '(39.3161400000, -76.5663900000)', '(39.3573500000, -76.6005300000)', '(39.3311200000, -76.6315100000)', '(39.3311200000, -76.6315100000)', '(39.2832900000, -76.5996300000)', '(39.2868200000, -76.6063900000)', '(39.3031200000, -76.6461100000)'] 
b = [ eval(x) for x in a ]
```

Comment: This is short and simple, even if it does use the dangerous `eval`.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to avoid `import`s and you feel
this may be the place to avoid list comprehension in favour of clarity*:

```
lst = ['(39.2947500000, -76.6565600000)', '(39.3423900000, -76.5698300000)', '(39.3199500000, -76.6222000000)', '(39.2533200000, -76.6263600000)', '(39.3068100000, -76.6549700000)', '(39.2937500000, -76.6233700000)', '(39.3146700000, -76.6425300000)', '(39.3073300000, -76.6015900000)', '(39.2451900000, -76.6336400000)', '(39.3283000000, -76.5893200000)', '(39.3215400000, -76.6736800000)', '(39.3010000000, -76.5977400000)', '(39.3122600000, -76.6194200000)', '(39.3161400000, -76.5663900000)', '(39.3573500000, -76.6005300000)', '(39.3311200000, -76.6315100000)', '(39.3311200000, -76.6315100000)', '(39.2832900000, -76.5996300000)', '(39.2868200000, -76.6063900000)', '(39.3031200000, -76.6461100000)']

out = list()
for i in lst:
    j,k = i.split(",")
    out.append(tuple((float(j[1:]), float(k[:-1]))))
print(out)
```

* See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/